# ColorCorrectionModel issue

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to perform color correction on images with a SG140 color checker. I'm just replicating the tutorial on OpenCV (4.6.0) website that you can find here:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc1/tutorial_ccm_color_correction_model.html

The color checker detection works flawlessly, I'm getting the RGB color patches correctly, the pixel values are provided to the ColorCorrectionModel instance (specifying COLORCHECKER_DigitalSG as color checker type). After the model is ran, I'm getting the CCM matrix to perform the color conversion. Internally the fitting is performed with a Downhill solver using a specific metric for color distance (CIE2000 as default). I tried to change the color distance, and by default a gamma linearization on colors is applied, but I can't get it working correctly.
Does anyone have found the same issue? Or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the ones that could face a similar issue in future... beware the order of colors. For some reasons, the color checker detector in OpenCV outputs color patches from bottom to top. And moreover the SG140 reference colors (the DigitalSG_LAB_D50_2 matrix in color.cpp, inside mcc module) is saved by columns (therefore from left to right).

Anyway I had success with closed form, but I still can't get a good fit with the cv::ccm::ColorCorrectionModel.